# Adverb or Noun?

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, nouns, parts-of-speech

I was taught that if there is only a single word after a preposition, it must be a Noun. For example,

> Our blessings come **from above**.

If I was taught right, the word **above** after the preposition **from** is a NOUN.

However, I don't have any reference to the rule I mentioned above. And **above** is listed in the dictionaries as an ADVERB. So what am I missing here?

Comment: Which dictionaries? https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/above#Noun

Comment: Sorry, but you were taught nonsense! Prepositions take a range of complements comparable to that of verbs: not just noun phrases, but preposition phrases, adverb phrases and clauses. Trad grammar treats "above" as an adverb, but some modern grammars treat it as a preposition. Either way "above" is functioning as complement of "from".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "above" can be used as a noun in a couple of limited, and one general way.

It can mean "heaven", "god" or metaphorically "the boss". This is what is meant in your quote. "Our blessings come from god/heaven"

The preposition "above" can also be used a noun elliptically, by removing the noun when the context makes the meaning clear.

> Is the aeroplane above or below the clouds?
>   It is above.

Here the word "above" means "above the clouds", but the context makes it clear.

Dictionaries, especially learner's dictionaries, might not include all the rare senses and uses of a word. But remember that you can never say "above is a noun", only "above is being used as a noun in this sentence".  Words only become parts of speech when they are used in a phrase or sentence.

Answer (score 1):

> *Our blessings come from above.*

Sorry, but you were taught nonsense!

Prepositions take a range of complements comparable to that of verbs: not just noun phrases, of course, but preposition phrases, adverb phrases and clauses (both finite and non-finite).

Trad grammar treats "above" as an adverb, but some modern grammars treat it as a preposition, in which case it's said to be 'stranded', i.e. not followed by the NP that is understood as its complement.

Whichever analysis is preferred, "above" is functioning as **complement** of "from".

Comment: We have a very poor education system and most of our school teachers hardly have any idea about what they are doing. :(